# Aligning div's horizontally in a line

Tags: html, css

I came across a scenario in which i have a parent container and inside that there will be a number of div's, which i need to display in one line.

**The requirements are:**

1. The number of div's will change
2. the width of each of the item's will differ
3. There should be a horizontal scroll bar in which we can swipe and select items.

I have tried with multiple solutions, but nothing is working as expected. When I tried with `display:inline-table` for child div's, it is working in PC and but fails in Iphone.

**The code looks like:**

```css
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  }
.child {
  display: inline-table;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Shirt</div>
  <div class="child">Jeans</div>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="child">Swetter</div>
  <div class="child">T-shirts<div>
 <div>
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Comment: you also want to to scroll horizontally in mobile??

Comment: yes ,It is basically a browser based mobile app.

Comment: Did you try inline-flex?

Comment: yes. not working as expected .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I have used `white-space: nowrap;` for the parent which align the child elements horizontally by adding a scrollbar
- Any no of child can be there and the width can be different in below example i have used the width of the content using `display:inline-block`

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto; /* change to overflow-x: scroll if you want to show scrollar if less elements */
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.parent > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>threeeee</div>
  <div>fiveeeeeeeeee</div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>threeeee</div>
  <div>fiveeeeeeeeee</div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>threeeee</div>
  <div>fiveeeeeeeeee</div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>threeeee</div>
  <div>fiveeeeeeeeee</div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>threeeee</div>
  <div>fiveeeeeeeeee</div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>threeeee</div>
  <div>fiveeeeeeeeee</div>
</div>
```